# Issue with AWS ResourceConflictException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

dealing with multiple logins using AWS cognito, meanwhile getting :

```
Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=10 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain error 10.)" UserInfo=0x7fca79661b10 {__type=ResourceConflictException, message=Cannot merge these identities.}]
```

My guess is : One cognitoID has facebook1, twiiter1 as linked logins, now second cognitoID tries to connect facebook2 which works but then tries to connect with twiiter1, in this case both cognito expected to be merged but there is conflict between facebook1 and facebook2 so getting `ResourceConflictException` . what would be possible fix to handle such case?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to use the same login with two different identities, Amazon Cognito Identity tries to merge the two identities.

It also restricts the identity to use only one login per provider. When the merge happens, since you have two facebook logins, you get a ResourceConflictException. This is a constraint with the implementation and cannot be handled at the service end.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. But this would be obvious case for apps dealing with multiple logins, Is there any suggestion/solution to handle such scenarios?

Comment: Apps dealing with multiple logins, to me, means that you need support for multiple login types on your app for the same user. What you are asking here is support for multiple users using same device and same login type. These two use cases are different and I don't understand why would you want to support the second one.